# C# Method to utilise linq expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-expressions

I have a number of similar methods that contain linq queries - here's an example. The only difference is the .Where clause fed by the param.

```
    public Supplier FindAny(int ID)
    {
         return CompareView.Select()
            .Where(p => p.Supplier.ID == ID)
            .Select(p => p.Supplier)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

I'm looking to see whether the code can be slimmed down through the use of expressions. To date I've found a few examples of expressions in use, but nothing that has helped me convert the code successfully.

Firstly, it would be good to know if expressions can be utilised with this style of code, and if it can, any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straight forward translation would be:

```
public Supplier FindAny(Func<WhateverTypePIs, bool> func)
{
     return CompareView.Select()
        .Where(func)
        .Select(p => p.Supplier)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

..which would allow this:

```
var supplier = FindAny(p => p.Supplier.ID == ID);
```

Note: You'll have to fill in the `WhateverTypePIs` generic type .. as that isn't shown in your original question (it's whatever `p`'s type is in your current expression).

Comment: Expression shouldn't be even necessary. 'Func<WhateverTypePIs, bool>' should suffice.

Comment: I've been messing around with this for quite a while - my code wasn't too disimilar to yours, but kept getting syntax errors. Your last sentence gave me the answer - I was passing supplier rather than Product, which is what 'p' is.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help:

```
public Supplier FindAny(Func<WhateverTypePIs, bool> func)
{
  return CompareView.FirstOrDefault(func).Supplier
}
```

Comment: That will throw a `NullReferenceException` if the predicate doesn't match anything.

Comment: Oops! Point is you may not need multiple Linqs. Perhaps `CompareView.FirstOrDefault( p => p.Supplier.ID == ID )` is sufficient